# Android Fragments Extra Code

Tags: android, android-fragments

I faced up a problem with my Android application. I'm a beginner and I tend to learn on my own. So I am trying to make a MediaPlayer and in order to do that, I need to use Fragments. The problem is not the Fragment itself but that I need to add some extra buttons with onClickListeners by the side of the MediaPlayer and my application is crashing because the fragment_main.xml file has the layout parameters but i cannot use the OnClickListener function in the Fragment(I get an error at findViewById(cannot make static reference to non-static method). Please help me.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 Button blade;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();


        /* blade = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fantab);
            blade.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                //On click function
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //Create the intent to start another activity
                    Intent vent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,     Ventscreen.class);
                    startActivity(vent);
                    finish();
                }
            });

    */      
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends ListFragment {

     private static final String[] FROM = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE };
        private static final int[] TO = { android.R.id.text1 };
        private CursorAdapter mAdapter;
        Button blade;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return view;
            blade = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fantab);
            blade.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                //On click function
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //Create the intent to start another activity
                    Intent vent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Ventscreen.class);
                    startActivity(vent);
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Context context = getActivity();
            int layout = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC");
            int flags = 0; 
            mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, layout, cursor, FROM, TO, flags);

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState); 

            setListAdapter(mAdapter); 
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    }
```

It is not just one button, the code above is just for example, there should be five buttons in total.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
blade = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fantab);
```

You're trying to call the `findViewById(int)` method of the outer `Activity`. This is not possible, sincer your inner `Fragment` class is static. What you want to do is call `findViewById(int)` on the `Fragment` `View`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    blade = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.fantab);
    blade.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        //On click function
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Create the intent to start another activity
            Intent vent = new Intent(getActivity(), Ventscreen.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(vent);
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Also, note the placement of the `return view;` statement.

Comment: I modified the code as you suggested and now there are two more errors at the "MainActivity.this" and "finish()". Please help me.

Comment: I've modified the answer. Please also read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: Thank you, it looks like it solved the problem, haven't got the chance to test it yet.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, the app crashes again when trying to start the new activity.
 01-18 06:55:15.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1120): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 06:55:15.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1120): Process: com.example.bgilca, PID: 1120
01-18 06:55:15.504: E/AndroidRuntime(1120): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bgilca/com.example.bgilca.Ventscreen}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08000a (com.example.bgilca:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{b446da40 #0 id=0x7f08000a}
here's the logcat message for it.any idea?

Comment: I searched for the address id in R.java, and the error is in the container id, however, i have no idea how to fix it.